# Disable JavaScript on Edge/IE

Tags: security, internet, personalization, microsoft-edge

Looking through the settings for Microsoft Edge, I don't see any obvious way to disable JavaScript. How can I disable JavaScript in Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this option is currently not available.

However, it is worth mentioning that the [Monument Browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/monument-browser/9nblggh1nsvj) has an option in its settings to disable JavaScript. This is the only way I've found to browse the web on a Windows phone without using JavaScript.